# Make any application into a global drop down application (Quake terminal style)

Tags: macos, applescript, window-manager, web-browser

I like to use a global hotkey to show/hide a terminal window. Many terminals have added support for this (originally popularized by terminal in Quake).

I want to do this for other things, like a web browser.

Ideal functionality :

- When global hotkey is pressed browser window drops down from whichever monitor has focus and on top of all other applications
- When global hotkey is pressed again the browser window will hide

If the solution requires using a different browser, i'm open to that. If it requires Applescript I can get my hands dirty. Just want a solution (ideally the solution could be used for other applications - currently just want browser and terminal and i get terminal support via iterm2 but I have an imagination).

Comment: Why not put each app in a different Space, then you have a ready-made hot key structure, rather than having to build your own?

Comment: I don't want to leave the current when I toggle browser to show. Specifically i don't want the browser to cover the entire screen (big monitor) so that it can be visible with whatever else is on the monitor at that point in time.

Comment: I wish you luck then ;)

Answer (score 1):

Found a decent answer to this question.

I used bettertouchtool to assign a custom keybinding to perform the action `Show/Hide Specific Application`. Seems to work pretty similar to what I'm going for.

Also another action that is relevant is the `Show Floating Webview`. You can direct this at a specific url.

There are some additional options within BTT to move applications to other displays as well. Currently i use the location of the mouse to determine active monitor that it will show/hide the browser on.

Comment: Can you describe *how* exactly you used BTT to accomplish this, by adding screenshots of relevant configurations etc?